# Facebook Fatal error Session has expired

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

```
<?php
require_once"includes/strings.php";
require_once"php/function.php";
require_once"php/config.php";
require_once"php/app.php";

$currentFBuserid = "0";

///////FACEBOOK GET USER INFORMATION
session_start();
// Enter the app id and secret below
define('YOUR_APP_ID', '$fbAppID');
define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', '$fbAppSecret');

require_once"php/fbsdk/src/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbAppID,
  'secret' => $fbAppSecret,
));

$userId = $facebook->getUser();
if($userId){
    $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId);
           }
```

Okay the issue is simple about every two hours I guess the session expires on my site and the error "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1352329200.

The current unix time is 1352330589. thrown in /home/######/public_html/php/fbsdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1238"

I'm having an impossible time figuring out what the issue is, no matter how long I scrape this site.

BTW:(refreshing the page solves the issue)

I really need help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Okay the issue is simple about every two hours I guess the session expires on my site and the error "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1352329200.

User access tokens acquired using the client-side flow expire after two hours.

You can either extend them, or use the server-side flow – both will result in a token that’s valid for 60 days.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

(The latest version of the PHP SDK has a method called `setExtendedAccessToken` for extending a short-lived token.)

> BTW:(refreshing the page solves the issue)

If you are using the JS SDK to do the login, then a refresh of course makes it do a new cross-domain request to Facebook, and will get a fresh short-lived access token.

Comment: Great! are you saying that I can't use both the JS SDK and the PHP SDK at the same time if I want a long live token? Either way I shall try and tell you if it's worked out

Comment: No, you can of course use them together – but _if_ you acquire the access token client-side (using the JS SDK), it will be short-lived, and you have to exchange it server-side for a long-lived one if you need one.

Comment: Thank you very much prepare yourself for a big ole check mark :P